# how to Grid without horizontal scroll and give vertical scroll header style

Tags: telerik, scrollbar, radgrid

I use radgrid with scrolling but when scrolling is on the header (see the [link](http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/5629/radgridheaderproblem.png)  for more info) of grid above the scroll looks different than the content header and on IE8 horizantal scroll is shown

The html markup of radgrid is below:

```
        <telerik:RadGrid HeaderStyle-Height="20px"  HeaderStyle-Width="500" BackColor="#ebebeb" ID="PropertySelectGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            runat="server" GridLines="None" Width="450px"  OnItemCreated="PropertySelectGrid_ItemCreated" TableLayout="Fixed" >
            <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="None"  BackColor="#ebebeb" Width="425px" CurrentResetPageIndexAction="SetPageIndexToFirst"
                Dir="LTR" Frame="Border" TableLayout="Fixed">                   
                <Columns>                        
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn ItemStyle-Width="0px" DataField="Id" Visible="false" DataType="system.string"
                        ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" UniqueName="Id">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Justify" ItemStyle-Width="20px" HeaderStyle-Width="20px" UniqueName="Selection">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox Width="15px" ID="SelectCheckBox" runat="server" TextAlign="Left"  AutoPostBack="false" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderStyle-Width="150px" DataType="system.string"
                        HeaderText="Adı" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Name" UniqueName="Name">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="PropertyValueColumn" ItemStyle-Width="200" HeaderStyle-Width="234" HeaderText="Değeri">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                </Columns>
                <NoRecordsTemplate>
                    Listelenecek Kayıt Bulunmamaktadır.</NoRecordsTemplate>
            </MasterTableView>
            <ClientSettings>
                <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" SaveScrollPosition="True" FrozenColumnsCount="1">
                </Scrolling>
            </ClientSettings>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

so how to disable horizontal scroll and headerstyle for vertical scroll like the content header?
Thanks